# Can't plot waveform data using Matplotlib but can using Excel from the same values

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a range of values in a csv file oscillating from -100 to 100 periodically.
This is how the plot looks like when I plot it in excel -
I selected the range of values -> Insert -> Insert Line -> Line
[image: excel plot]

When I import it in Python using pandas, and plot that row using Matplotlib, I get this image -
Here, time is an array of values from 0 to 1000 with a step of 0.5
[image: matplotlib]

The full code -

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("p_wave/Before/25/B25.csv")
time = np.arange(0,1000,0.5)
y_val = [0]*2000
for i in range(2000):
    y_val[i]=df.iloc[18][i]
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(time, y_val)
```

Since the csv file is huge, I'm attaching a [link](https://github.com/rohithandique/FFT-Python/blob/main/p_wave/Before/25/B25.csv) for it on my github. It it the 18th row.

I do not know why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need some parameters to tell `read_csv` more information about your csv file.  Or create a more standard version of the csv.  One of the problems is that your column 18 now contains strings.

Comment: Matplotlib treats strings as "categories".  You need to convert your strings to floats...

Comment: @JodyKlymak changing the series' datatype to float (with astype(float)) works perfectly! thank you so much!